# Format for dates in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, date-format

I have a data frame with a date column where there are different type of date formats present. I want to validate and extract only the records with date format `'MM-dd-yy'` but when I validate and extract  I am also getting the records with format '`'MM-dd-yyyy'.` What is the correct format to extract the records with format '`'MM-dd-yy'?`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F,Window
df = sc.parallelize([['12-21-20'],
                     ['05-30-2020'],
                     ['01-01-1984'],
                     ['12-24-20']]).toDF(["Date"])

df.show()
+----------+
|      Date|
+----------+
|  12-21-20|
|05-30-2020|
|01-01-1984|
|  12-24-20|
+----------+
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
df=df.filter(~F.col("Date").isNotNull()|
                                           to_date(F.col("Date"),'MM-dd-yy').isNotNull()) 
display(df)
+----------+
|      Date|
+----------+
|  12-21-20|
|05-30-2020|
|01-01-1984|
|  12-24-20|
+----------+
```

Expected output:

```
+----------+
|      Date|
+----------+
|  12-21-20|
|  12-24-20|
+----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simple way not using `to_date` but rather [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html?highlight=regexp#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract)

```
df = df.filter((F.regexp_extract('Date', '(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})$', 1) != '') & 
               (F.to_date('Date', 'MM-dd-yy').isNotNull()))
df.show()

+--------+
|    Date|
+--------+
|12-21-20|
|12-24-20|
+--------+
```

Comment: I think this will not do date format verification. What if I pass month as 22?

Comment: You are right, I forgot about that part. Answer updated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can specify format as `MM-dd-yyyy`, it will append `00` to the year with 2 digits and you can filter based on that.

```
df.where(to_date(F.col("Date"),'MM-dd-yyyy').rlike('^00[1-9]+') &
to_date(F.col("Date"),'MM-dd-yyyy').isNotNull()).show()

+--------+
|    Date|
+--------+
|12-21-20|
|12-24-20|
+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

using rlike and to_date

```
>>> df.filter((f.col("Date").rlike('^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$')) 
            & (f.to_date(f.col("Date"), "MM-dd-yy")).isNotNull()).show()
+--------+
|    Date|
+--------+
|12-21-20|
|12-24-20|
+--------+
```